# Open XML Files With ASP Extension

Tags: php, xml

I got a problem. I can not access XML file in a server with ASP extension from PHP. Is there anyone who knows how to get XML files with different extension from php?

XML File Address:http://petbesinleri.com/xml-bayi/urun.asp

Thank you anyway...

Comment: If you're accessing via a URL, then the extension is not causing you any problem, the url is.... how are you trying to access this file? file_get_contents()? curl()? Perhaps the owners of petbesinleri.com object to access from a script rather than from a browser.

Comment: Do you want to read an xml using php or asp?

Comment: I try to read it in PHP. 
I tried both curl and file_get_contents, in addition to these i also tried DOMDocument. it always returns the same response:".. failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request in .."

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem.

I said I used curl. Solution comes from CURL again. I never tried to add useragent parameter for curl. When I added that parameter as current google chrome browser, my problem was gone.

Thank you for all people who even read my problem.